# Spotfire - Biquery - Simba JDBC

Tags: google-bigquery, spotfire, simba

I could not find an anwser to the following question. I have been testing **Spotfire** with BigQuery connector in the last week. I am using [Simba JDBC driver](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-jdbc-data-access-connectivity-details#toc-18). it works well ~1min per Go of Data import to memory. This is fast thanks to the **BigQuery Storage API** implementation⚡

What I cannot understand are the 2 following points:

1. Which version of Simba Driver and Spotfire have this highthroughput feature enabled?
2. Can I configure this feature? Adding [EnableHighThroughputAPI=1](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/enablehighthroughputapi.htm) in the connection string toggles BQ storage API use. In Spotfire, changing this parameter from 1 to 0 does not make any difference - Storage API is always used. Is it internally overwritten by Spotfire?

An expert insight would be appreciated - I could not find a documentation on that (I am using 11.2.0 HF002 and simba jdbc42).

thanks!

Comment: Are you using the BigQuery connector (like you say) or are you using Information Services (which is the only Spotfire data access mechanism that uses JDBC)?